# angularjs:using xmlhttprequest to add data to $scope rather than $http, but it unworks

Tags: angularjs, http, callback, scope, xmlhttprequest

I am studying 'XHRs & Dependency Injection' by official tutorial of angularjs.

It introduce $http service to get json from some file under same domain.

I wanna try original XMLHttpRequest to get json.

I get the data but nothing displayed on the view, there should be a list of phones when using $http.

demo code:

```
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.phones = data;
  });
```

[image]

what i wrote to replace:

```
var xmlhttp=null;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if(xmlhttp!=null)
  {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=state_Change;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", 'phones/phones.json', true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
  }
  else{
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
  }

  function state_Change()
  {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {// 4 = "loaded"
      if(xmlhttp.status==200)
      {// 200 = OK
        var phoneList=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        $scope.phones=phoneList;
        console.log($scope); // ChildScope {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array[3], $$listeners: Object…}

        console.log($scope.phones); // object, actually what is.But it can't be reflected to the view.There is nothing where should be a list.
              }
              else{
                alert("Problem retrieving XML data");
              }
            }
          }
```

[image]

Comment: you haven't get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment is performed in `onreadystatechange` event handler. And the event is fired outside of angular digestion cycle. In such cases you have to tell angular to detect changes. You'd do this using `$applyAsync` method of your `$scope`:

```
...
var phoneList=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
$scope.$applyAsync(function(){
   $scope.phones=phoneList;
})
...
```

But normally you just should use `$http` as entre suggested. It deals with digestion for you.

Comment: thank you so much. I have a look at the developer guide and find $scope.$apply also can do that. The difference between $apply and $applyAsync is the latter to occur at a later time.

Comment: using `$apply` you always risk to get `already in digest cycle` error if you ever call your function from inside existing angular digest cycle. Your `state_Change` function isn't aware of the context it is called in. However if you 100% sure that this function will only be used as `xmlhttprequest` event handler it's fine to use `$apply`

Comment: did it answer your question?